# BBP: How to secure database ids in a messaging system?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have a simple system for messaging. Coded in PHP, MySQL and maybe Java will be implemented. Now I want to secure the ids of the recipients. At the moment I use the autoincremented primary keys (1, 2, 3) of the user table. But this is to unsecure, of course. Because everybody can guess, all other ids by counting from 1 to xxx. So what is the best busniess pratice to secure the id. Convert it in MD5 (maybe with some passwort text "myencryptionkey" + userId --> MD5)?
If the recipient id is to easy to reproduce, spammers will use this system for their purposes.

I think  this is a general problem. As well as for "friendship invitations". If everybod can guess, how the ids are constructed, you can send tons of friendship invitations.

**Another idea:**
Whats about encrypting the userIds with an randomly created key. I generate a random key an store it in the session cookie. So everybody has an other identifier for user 123. So I need a function to encrypt and decrypt with a given integer.

How do pages like facebook protec their primary keys?

Answer (score 1):

IDs are usually predictable. This is not a problem.

By making them non-predicable you essentially make the IDs a secret. Whomever knows the secret has access. This is called [security by obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and is not secure *at all*.

If you want to restrict access, you should put some access control measure in place. For example, let people log in and give view rights based on their userId/role.

Comment: Your are right. I will prevent that user can write message to other uses, that are not in the friendlist. So if someone manipulates the receiver id, the message will not be send. Bacuase the manipulated userid is not in a freindship relation, ok. But what is with invitations? Of course verybod must be able to send a friendship invitation to everbody else. Maybe the messaging examlpe was not the boest one. How to prevent that a spammer / hacker can guess the ids ans send tons of invitations? In my opinion this can just be doen by encrypting the ids.

Comment: @brill 
I'd then suggest just adding to regular numeric IDs also name of the user (only for the link to their profile), like `example.com/profile/123slava`. You won't make it any more secure by encrypting, you'll just lose performance. User's first/last name will be kind of a password for regular primary key with least inconvinience for normal users and without performance loss for dealing with obfuscated IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I only see the problem if your system has holes that allow people to exploit your identifiers, though I understand the concern and it has crossed my mind on occasion, for this reason I might suggest, though not necessarily be a proponent of, using a `GUID` for each unique key.

These can be auto-generated on insertion of records, and eradicate the guessability factor.

They do also expand the size quite significantly, I would say, in comparison to an integer - this being problematic depends on the scale and other areas of the system.

Comment: Surely MySQL supports auto-generation of GUIDs on a field as identity, you shouldn't need to generate and insert these yourself at all.

Comment: When using GUIDs keep the GUID=>ID mapping in a separate table and stay with numeric ids in all other tables. That ensures you have only minimal performance loss (the time to lookup GUID=>ID) instead of having to do string-based lookups everytime you access an obfuscated primary key.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: That is simply just redundancy.